# comparing two dictionary lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have two dictionaries

```
{key1:[list_of_objects ], {key2:[list_of_objects ]}
```

e.g

```
dict1 = {key1:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ], key2: ['f', 'g', 'h' ] }
dict2 = {key1:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],  key2: ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i' ] }
```

For eack key in both dict1 and dict2, i want to compare the items in the lists.

i.e compare each value in dict1[key1] with the correcponding value in dict2[key1]  and so on. The items in the lists are objects, so will runing something like

```
if dict1[key1][0].some_function() = = dict2[key1][0].some_function()
     then condition
```

what is the fastest way to run this comparision?

Comment: do you have a working way to do this? once you do, it'll be time to worry about the speed.

Comment: What do you want to do with 'i' in dict2[key2]? It has no corresponding value in dict1.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do.  

I'm assuming you have a class MyClass which has a member function some_function which calculates a number (or other comparable) that can be compared by ==.

Now, do you want to do something on every match without caring about order in the list?  If dict1['key1'] = [A,B,C] and dict2['key1']=[B,C,A] should it find any matches?  (Presumably No, since the lists don't line up).  Do you need all the objects in the list keys to match prior to doing something?  Do you want to iterate through all keys or just compare key1?

Comment: i guess the lists have to be ordered for matching to work perfect and if there are items in once list and not in the other list, the if test should fail on those items - and therefore logged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key in dict1.keys():
    for a,b in zip(dict1[key],dict2[key]):
        if a.some_function() == b.some_function():
           #do something
```

If your lists are very long you could swap `zip` for `izip` from `collections`.

Comment: This actually works assumming the entries in the lists are ordered and equal in length.

Comment: @json If they're not the same length you have nothing to compare.  Or were you planning to run an action when the items were different rather than just when they were the same?

Comment: compare, similar items and log those that are not in either list - but the above worked for me, i just added a check to ensure lists are the same lenght.

Comment: @json This answer does not assume anything about the order of the items in the list or their lengths, it does not even assume that they're lists.  All those assumptions are inside the `do something`.

Answer (score 0):

sets make it easy:

```
for key in dict1.keys():
    diff = set(dict1[key]).symmetric_difference(dict2[key])
    if diff:
        print "%s: %s" % (key, diff)  # or do whatever
```

Comment: Two problems here.  1. This doesn't cover running the `some_function` method.  2. The OP wants to do something when the items are the same, not when they are different.

Comment: Good points. I think I was confused by the OP's original explanation of the problem and by the use of strings in the example.

Comment: Since the OP later clarified that order is important, I'm not going to bother updating this sets-based solution.